# Sub-menu of an horizontal dropdown doesn't go vertical

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a horizontal dropdown menu that has a sub-menu.
This sub-menu is supposed to go vertical but it goes horizontal.
i've tried solutions to similar problem in this forum but they don't work for me.

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
body{
 font-family: 'Francois One', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 color: white;
 text-align:center; 
}
.corpo{
 margin-top: 5px;
 margin-left:  20%;
 margin-right: 15%;
 float:middle;
 
}
header{
 margin: 40px 0;
}
.menu li{
 display: block;
 float: left;
 clear: right;
 width: 10%;
 height: 50px;
 line-height: 50px;
 text-align: center;
 color: #2C3E50;
 border-right: 1px solid #2C3E50;
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #FFFF00 50%, #FFFF00 51%, #f6f6f6 100%);
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #FFFF00 50%, #FFFF00 51%, #f6f6f6 100%);
 background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #FFFF00 50%, #FFFF00 51%, #f6f6f6 100%);
 background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #FFFF00 50%, #FFFF00 51%, #f6f6f6 100%);
 border-color:black;
 opacity:1;
 position:relative;
}
.menu li:hover{
 cursor: pointer;
 background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, #ffffff 0%, #e5e5e5 100%);
 background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, #ffffff 0%, #e5e5e5 100%);
 background: -o-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, #ffffff 0%, #e5e5e5 100%);
 background: -ms-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, #ffffff 0%, #e5e5e5 100%);
 color: slateGrey;
 border-color:black;
 position:relative;
}
.primo{
 border-top-left-radius: 10px;
 border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}
.ultimo{
 border-top-right-radius: 10px;
 border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}
.sub-menu{
 visibility: hidden;
 width: 1000%;
 float:center;
 
 
 
}
.menu li:hover .sub-menu{
 visibility: visible;
 
}
.menu li:hover .sub-menu li{
 visibility: visible;
 display:inline;
 clear:left;
 clear:right;


 
 
} 
.sub-menu li{
 border-top: 1px dotted #2C3E50;
 
}
.sub-menu li:hover{
 width: 145px;
 background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, #f7fbfc 10%, #add9e4 100%);
 background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, #f7fbfc 10%, #add9e4 100%);
 background: -o-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, #f7fbfc 10%, #add9e4 100%);
 background: -ms-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, #f7fbfc 10%, #add9e4 100%);
 transition: all 0.1s ease 0s;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease 0s;
 -moz-transition: all 0.1s ease 0s;
 -o-transition: all 0.1s ease 0s;
 -ms-transition: all 0.1s ease 0s;
}
.ultimo-sub{
 border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
 border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}

.menu li a:link{
color:black;
text-decoration:none;
}

.menu li a:hover{
color:black;
text-decoration:none;
}

.menu li a:active{
color:black;
text-decoration:none;

}

.menu ul li:hover ul{
 position:relative;
 display:block;
}

.menu li a:visited{
color:black;
text-decoration:none;

}

p{
 color: #FFFF00;
 margin: 0px 380px 0px 400px;
 font-size:150%;
 text-shadow: 2px 0 0 #000, 0 -1px 0 #000, 0 2px 0 #000, -1px 0 0 #000;               //text-shadow: 2px 0 0 #000, 0 -1px 0 #000, 0 2px 0 #000, -1px 0 0 #000;
 
}

.Paragrafo{
 text-shadow:1px 0 0 #000, 0 -1px 0 #000, 0 1px 0 #000, -1px 0 0 #000;
 size:25px;
}

.Paragrafo  a:link{
color:yellow;
}

.Paragrafo a:hover{
color:yellow;
}

.Paragrafo  a:active{
color:yellow;
}

.Paragrafo  a:visited{
color:yellow;
}

h1{
 color:blue;
 
}

span{
 color: #FFFF00;
 margin: 0px 380px 0px 400px;
 font-size:150%;
 text-shadow: 2px 0 0 #000, 0 -1px 0 #000, 0 2px 0 #000, -1px 0 0 #000;               //text-shadow: 2px 0 0 #000, 0 -1px 0 #000, 0 2px 0 #000, -1px 0 0 #000;
 
}

.video{
 position: 404 532;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Menù a tendina in HTML e CSS</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="new 1(!).css">
  <style> h1 {color:yellow;
              float:center;
             } </style>     
 </head>     
  <body background="ww1.png" class="1">
  
 
  
   <header>
    <h1>La Grande Guerra</h1>
   </header>
  <div class="corpo">
   <ul class="menu">
    <li class="primo"><a href="SitoHome2(!).html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="1914.html">1914</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="1915.html">1915</a>
     <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li><a href="1915-1.html">Da 01 a 04</a></li>
      <li><a href="1915-2.html">Da 05 a 08</a></li>
      <li class="ultimo-sub"><a href="1915-3.html">Da 09 a 12</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="1916.html">1916</a>
     <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li><a href="1916-1.html">Da 01 a 04</a></li>
      <li><a href="1916-2.html">Da 05 a 08</a></li>
      <li class="ultimo-sub"><a href="1916-3.html">Da 09 a 12</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="1917.html">1917</a>
     <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li><a href="1917-1.html">Da 01 a 04</a></li>
      <li><a href="1917-2.html">Da 05 a 08</a></li>
      <li class="ultimo-sub"><a href="1917-3.html">Da 09 a 12</a></li>
     </ul>
       </li>
    <li><a href="1918.html">1918</a>
     <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li class="ultimo-sub"><a href="1918-1.html">Eventi</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Armistizio</a>
     <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li class="ultimo-sub"><a href="#">Conseguenze</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="Galleria.html">Galleria</a>
     <ul class="sub-menu">
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="ultimo"><a href="Fonti.html">Fonti</A></li>
    
   </ul>
  </div> <BR> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> 
  <div class=Paragrafi>
  <p>
        TEXT
  <object class=video width="420" height="315"data="https://www.youtube.com/embed/6FgaL0xIazk?list=PLB2vhKMBjSxOb_127vxjaRRC7yu2TJlJX"
  float=left align=right>
        </object>
  </p>
  <p align=left>
        Text
  </p> 
   

  
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue lays with your clear property. You are overwriting the `clear:left;` with `clear:right;`. You should use `clear: both;` instead

```
.menu li:hover .sub-menu li{
    visibility: visible;
    display:inline;
    clear:left; /* this property gets overwritten by clear: right */
    clear:right;
}
```

Fix

```
 .menu li:hover .sub-menu li{
        visibility: visible;
        display:inline;
        clear:both;
    }
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  font-family: 'Francois One', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
.corpo {
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-left: 20%;
  margin-right: 15%;
  float: middle;
}
header {
  margin: 40px 0;
}
.menu li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  clear: right;
  width: 10%;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2C3E50;
  border-right: 1px solid #2C3E50;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #FFFF00 50%, #FFFF00 51%, #f6f6f6 100%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #FFFF00 50%, #FFFF00 51%, #f6f6f6 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #FFFF00 50%, #FFFF00 51%, #f6f6f6 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #FFFF00 50%, #FFFF00 51%, #f6f6f6 100%);
  border-color: black;
  opacity: 1;
  position: relative;
}
.menu li:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, #ffffff 0%, #e5e5e5 100%);
  background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, #ffffff 0%, #e5e5e5 100%);
  background: -o-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, #ffffff 0%, #e5e5e5 100%);
  background: -ms-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, #ffffff 0%, #e5e5e5 100%);
  color: slateGrey;
  border-color: black;
  position: relative;
}
.primo {
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}
.ultimo {
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}
.sub-menu {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 1000%;
  float: center;
}
.menu li:hover .sub-menu {
  visibility: visible;
}
.menu li:hover .sub-menu li {
  visibility: visible;
  display: inline;
  clear: both;
}
.sub-menu li {
  border-top: 1px dotted #2C3E50;
}
.sub-menu li:hover {
  width: 145px;
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, #f7fbfc 10%, #add9e4 100%);
  background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, #f7fbfc 10%, #add9e4 100%);
  background: -o-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, #f7fbfc 10%, #add9e4 100%);
  background: -ms-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, #f7fbfc 10%, #add9e4 100%);
  transition: all 0.1s ease 0s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.1s ease 0s;
  -o-transition: all 0.1s ease 0s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.1s ease 0s;
}
.ultimo-sub {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}
.menu li a:link {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.menu li a:hover {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.menu li a:active {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.menu ul li:hover ul {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}
.menu li a:visited {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}
p {
  color: #FFFF00;
  margin: 0px 380px 0px 400px;
  font-size: 150%;
  text-shadow: 2px 0 0 #000, 0 -1px 0 #000, 0 2px 0 #000, -1px 0 0 #000;               //text-shadow: 2px 0 0 #000, 0 -1px 0 #000, 0 2px 0 #000, -1px 0 0 #000;
}
.Paragrafo {
  text-shadow: 1px 0 0 #000, 0 -1px 0 #000, 0 1px 0 #000, -1px 0 0 #000;
  size: 25px;
}
.Paragrafo a:link {
  color: yellow;
}
.Paragrafo a:hover {
  color: yellow;
}
.Paragrafo a:active {
  color: yellow;
}
.Paragrafo a:visited {
  color: yellow;
}
h1 {
  color: blue;
}
span {
  color: #FFFF00;
  margin: 0px 380px 0px 400px;
  font-size: 150%;
  text-shadow: 2px 0 0 #000, 0 -1px 0 #000, 0 2px 0 #000, -1px 0 0 #000;               //text-shadow: 2px 0 0 #000, 0 -1px 0 #000, 0 2px 0 #000, -1px 0 0 #000;
}
.video {
  position: 404 532;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Menù a tendina in HTML e CSS</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="new 1(!).css">
  <style>
    h1 {
      color: yellow;
      float: center;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body background="ww1.png" class="1">



  <header>
    <h1>La Grande Guerra</h1>
  </header>
  <div class="corpo">
    <ul class="menu">
      <li class="primo"><a href="SitoHome2(!).html">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="1914.html">1914</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="1915.html">1915</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li><a href="1915-1.html">Da 01 a 04</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="1915-2.html">Da 05 a 08</a>
          </li>
          <li class="ultimo-sub"><a href="1915-3.html">Da 09 a 12</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="1916.html">1916</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li><a href="1916-1.html">Da 01 a 04</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="1916-2.html">Da 05 a 08</a>
          </li>
          <li class="ultimo-sub"><a href="1916-3.html">Da 09 a 12</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="1917.html">1917</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li><a href="1917-1.html">Da 01 a 04</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="1917-2.html">Da 05 a 08</a>
          </li>
          <li class="ultimo-sub"><a href="1917-3.html">Da 09 a 12</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="1918.html">1918</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li class="ultimo-sub"><a href="1918-1.html">Eventi</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Armistizio</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li class="ultimo-sub"><a href="#">Conseguenze</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="Galleria.html">Galleria</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="ultimo"><a href="Fonti.html">Fonti</A>
      </li>

    </ul>
  </div>
  <BR>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <div class=Paragrafi>
    <p>
      TEXT
      <object class=video width="420" height="315" data="https://www.youtube.com/embed/6FgaL0xIazk?list=PLB2vhKMBjSxOb_127vxjaRRC7yu2TJlJX" float=left align=right>
      </object>
    </p>
    <p align=left>
      Text
    </p>



</body>

</html>
```

Extra remarks: there's no such thing as `float: center;` or `float: middle;`, see [float docs on mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float)
You're also not using `position` correctly, see [position docs on mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

Comment: Thanks Sniels , you saved my ass and also taught me some new thing about css.

Comment: @LivioBorgogna Please, mark the answer as correct if it solved your question.